# How to change font colors for directories with write permissions in ls?

Tags: ls, colors

When I do `ls -1`, I get colours that I don't like:

[image: ls output with horrid blue on green text]

These directories (folder1, folder2, folder3) have "anyone can do anything" permissions.
(also called 777 permissions I think).

I'm not partial to the the blue font with green background.

How do I change the font colors for directories with these permissions?

> OS: Ubuntu 19.04
>
> Shell: Zsh

Comment: Create and delete permission is write permission (but all so see sticky bit). And the permission 777 is **anyone** can do **anything**.

Comment: What command did you do to get that output?

Comment: I used the command `ls -1`.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me in ZSH.

I ran

```
 dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

I then added the following line to the bottom of my `.zshrc` file.

```
eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)";
```

Then I opened `.dircolors` in an editor and changed the numbers in the following line:

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 01;35 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

35 corresponds to magenta.

I then restarted my ZSH by running

```
~/.zshrc
```

twice

[image]